# Cannot Call pointer method on and Cannot take address of [maps golang]

Tags: pointers, dictionary, methods, go, hashmap

I have a function `GetMySqlConn(variable bool) (db gorm.DB) {..` which returns the `gorm.DB` for mySQL connection.

*Case 1* : My code looks like this:

```
var (
    MysqlConn         gorm.DB
)

func main(){

    MysqlConn = GetMySqlConn(false)

    result := MysqlConn.Raw(sqlQuery).Row()
    result.Scan(&id)
    fmt.Println(id)
    :
}
```

**Which works fine. BUT**

*Case 2*: When i try to convert `MysqlConn` to a map :

```
var (
        MysqlConn         map[int]gorm.DB
    )

func main(){

    MysqlConn = make(map[int]gorm.DB)
    MysqlConn[0] = GetMySqlConn(false)

    // AND THEN DO THIS
    result := MysqlConn[0].Raw(sqlQuery).Row()
    result.Scan(&id)
    fmt.Println(id)
    :
}
```

**It throws me the error**

```
:
cannot call pointer method on MysqlConn[0]
cannot take the address of MysqlConn[0]
:
```

**Now**

*Case 3* : Considering the error, I try to get its workaround and change my code to this:

```
var (
        MysqlConn         map[int]*gorm.DB
        tempMysqlConn     gorm.DB
    )

func main(){

    MysqlConn = make(map[int]*gorm.DB)
    tempMysqlConn = GetMySqlConn(false)
    MysqlConn[0] = &tempMysqlConn

    // AND THEN DO THIS
    result := MysqlConn[0].Raw(sqlQuery).Row()
    result.Scan(&id)
    fmt.Println(id)
    :
}
```

**IT WORKS**

Now since i'm new to Golang i'm not exactly getting what's the reason for the error even though i somehow got to the solution.

So what i want to ask is when i access the `method` of `gorm.DB` structure through a simple `gorm.DB` type variable `MysqlConn` (in Case 1), it works.

BUT when i DO THE SAME in Case 2 but now with a map ( again having the same `gorm.DB` type value) it DOESN'T WORK and throws me the error and i've to `convert` its value type to a `pointer` first (i.e `*gorm.DB`) (Case 3).

So why with Map values do i have to create a pointer type to access the `method` where it's possible without the pointer type if you do it with a simple variable?

Comment: To put it succinctly, map values are not addressable.

Comment: Yeah, read the link mentioned. Somehow didn't find the question before posting (don't know if i should delete it). Thanks though